# 22.10 Does not attach to a Realtek Wifi Adpater

Tags: realtek-wireless

Tower PC, AMD 64-bit, newer hardware, PSU, Mobo and HDDs, and have run Ubuntu since 16.04, just installed 22.10 a couple weeks ago. Since then...

Problem: Since installing Ubuntu 22.10, it lists but does not attach to the Realtek wifi adapters I try to use. As in past versions of the OS, it favors RaLink adapter and doesn't show or connect to my Realtek adapters. It had worked between versions 20.04 and 21.04 after hours of work by me and one of the contributors here on AskUbuntu, heynnema, so it would keep working past the update boundary but now it looks like it's broken again. (I tested the adapter on Win10 just now and it's working fine there, as is the Ralink adapter and they worked concurrently in Win10).

Before 22.10, using version 21.04, the Network dropdown list showed the received Wifi stations for BOTH adapters, now only shows those from the Ralink adapter.

```
lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1871:0142 Aveo Technology Corp. USB2.0 Camera
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 048d:5702 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. ITE Device
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 045e:0047 Microsoft Corp. IntelliMouse Explorer 3.0
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1267:0103 Logic3 / SpectraVideo plc G-720 Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 0bda:a811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8811AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 058f:6364 Alcor Micro Corp. AU6477 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

So does anyone know of a fix for this? A permanent fix that will make Ubuntu see or install Realtek wifi adapter drivers when upgraded? Or how to get it to read the Realtek adapter NOW.

Thanks.

Edit: Yes, both adapters show up in the above listing, but NOT in the drop down listing of available Networks in the GUI. There should be two listings, there's only one, and it's only the stations the Ralink can receive (it's a tiny device on the back of the Tower's case...the Realtek is a high gain device in a 6" square package tethered by a 10 meter cable that I move to where it can best see the signals I want to attach to).

EDIT: Software & Updates does show the drivers, but why doesn't it work?

[image: Software and Updates Additional Drivers tab open...]

Comment: If I drop down the NETWORK stuff from the taskbar, only ONE adapters list of Wifi networks are shown. I know from using these adapters before that there should be TWO lists of wifi networks including the 2 I'm interested in that the high gain adapter finds but the tiny Ralink adapter can't see. So yes, it shows in the listing but the Network isn't shown. I have no idea how to get around that...to get 22.10 to show both networking adapters outputs that would allow me to connect to those missing networks.

Comment: I can't see how to tag @heynnema as he's the one here on this forum that has helped me with this problem of Ubuntu dropping access to Realtek adapaters in the past. I see the 'Share a link to this question' below, but I thought there was a way inside of this forum to tag an expert, I just can't find it now. Anyone care to give me some instructions? Thanks.

Comment: SOLVED with the help of the Ubuntu bug report system at launchpad using the IRC system. What the tech had me do was download and install an updated driver for the Realtek wifi adapter I'm using. Where he found it, I don't know but it's dated 2021. Driver is 8821au-20210708. When finishing restoring operation, he told me that there wouldn't be a fix for this problem of the adapter driver not working after some Ubuntu updates and upgrades. GRRRR.

Comment: Had Ubuntu 23.04 trash my system when trying to upgrade (seemed to install fine, but on reboot showed the BSOD and I wasn't able to recover the system so it would reboot) so dropped back to my full cloned backup. And haven't needed the Realtek adapter until now, and sure enough, it does show up in lsusb, but does not show up or work in the GUI. Still having trouble with it.